# VBA Excel copy data from 2 different worksheets in a third one

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I would like to copy the data from 'Sheet1' ($A:$N ; may fluctuate), select the range of the data and paste it in 'Sheet3'.

I also need to copy the data from 'Sheet2' without the first row (same headers as 'Sheet1') and paste it underneath the data of 'Sheet1' that is now in 'Sheet3'.

```
Sub CopyPaste() 
    Sheets("PC_VIEWS").Select 
    Range("A1:Q231").Select 
    Selection.Copy 
    Sheets("PC_LTC_VIEWS").Select 
    Range("A1").Select 
    ActiveSheet.Paste 
    Range("A1").Select 
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select 
    Range("A232").Select 
    Sheets("LTC_VIEWS").Select 
    Range("A1").Select 
    Application.CutCopyMode = False 
    Range("A1:M1264").Select 
    Selection.Copy 
    Sheets("PC_LTC_VIEWS").Select 
    ActiveSheet.Paste 
End Sub
```

I am open to other solutions!

Comment: This is the code I am using when I record the macro, however as the PC_VIEWS data is looking to grow, starting the LTC_VIEWS at A232 won't work

Sub CopyPaste()
    Sheets("PC_VIEWS").Select
    Range("A1:Q231").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("PC_LTC_VIEWS").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Range("A232").Select
    Sheets("LTC_VIEWS").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("A1:M1264").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("PC_LTC_VIEWS").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub

Comment: You can edit your question and put the code in there, which will allow you to format it so that it's readable.

Comment: What is your problem. Is this code work?

Comment: My issue is that when I paste the second worksheet into the 3rd one after the first, it would paste it at the cell A232 which is the next cell after the range of Sheet1. However my data will expand overtime and if it does then Sheet2 will overwrite data starting from A232. Does this makes sense?
Ideally I would like to code Select Range Sheet1 - Paste in Sheet3. Select Range Sheet2, go under Data column A(ctrl+arrow down, arrow down) Sheet3, paste data of Sheet2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is enough. Try it.

```
Public Sub CopyAndPaste()

    Dim firstRowCount, secondRowCount As Integer

    'Copy from "PC_VIEWS" sheet.
    Sheets("PC_VIEWS").Select

    'Getting the last row from "PC_VIEWS" sheet.
    firstRowCount = Range("A:Q").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).row

    Range("A1:Q" & firstRowCount).Select

    Selection.Copy

    'Paste to "PC_LTC_VIEWS" sheet.
    Sheets("PC_LTC_VIEWS").Select

    Range("A1").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    'Reset clipboard
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'Copy from "LTC_VIEWS" sheet.
    Sheets("LTC_VIEWS").Select

    'Getting the last row from "LTC_VIEWS" sheet.
    secondRowCount = Range("A:Q").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).row

    Range("A2:Q" & secondRowCount).Select

    Selection.Copy

    'Paste to "PC_LTC_VIEWS" sheet.
    Sheets("PC_LTC_VIEWS").Select

    Range("A" & firstRowCount + 1).Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    'Reset clipboard
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Range("A1:Q231").Select will that range selection fluctuate according to the data in the sheet? Same question here: Range("A2:Q1264").Select - Range("A232").Select: how can I select the next cell down the data of that selection Range("A1:Q231") if it fluctuates?